# Is there a better way to write this loop around lists so that it will not give a Memory Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I have the following Python code:

```
for i in range(0, len(oscillations) - sequence_length):
    a = patterns[i:i + sequence_length]
    b = oscillations[i:i + sequence_length]
    sequence_in = [a+b for a,b in zip(a,b)]
    sequence_out = oscillations[i + sequence_length]  
    network_input.append(sequence_in)
    network_output.append(sequence_out)
```

The length of oscillations is 212922. Each element of oscillations has a length of 25. The length of patterns is exactly the same. Both lists have the same structure, but with different data.

The above code code fails, it gives me a MemoryError. Sometimes while going through the loop, sometimes when returning both lists.

If I shorten the lists to around 100000 elements then it works.

I understand this is probably me trying to allocate too much in memory, but my question is, if there's a smarter way to go through my lists so that it won't need to allocate that much memory.

Comment: What *type* of data do your lists contain: `float`, `int`, `str`, or a mixture?

Comment: what are you doing with the output lists? if you don't need random access, you could `yield` the items to make generators instead

Comment: Maybe thats an helpfull link for you: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609

Comment: What is your code *doing*? You need to provide more context.

Comment: You also can use numpy arrays to determine explicit a small datatype.

Comment: @jpp it contains "float"

Comment: @Chris_Rands the output lists are used for training a RNN using keras

Answer (score 1):

as some commenters pointed out you probably don't need to build the whole lists `network_input` and `network_output`. The biggest improvement to memory consumption would be to `yield` instead:

```
def stuff(oscillations, sequence_length, patterns):
    for i in range(0, len(oscillations) - sequence_length):
        a = patterns[i:i + sequence_length]
        b = oscillations[i:i + sequence_length]
        sequence_in = [a + b for a, b in zip(a, b)]
        sequence_out = oscillations[i + sequence_length]
        yield (sequence_in, sequence_out)

for s in stuff(oscillations, sequence_length, patterns):
    print(s)
```

The other, smaller improvements would be gained by noticing you slice and sum the same elements from both collections many times. `a` and `b` only differ by one element each between iterations. You could use a simple moving sum algorithm:

```
def moving_stuff(oscillations, sequence_length, patterns):
    ops = []
    sums = []
    for op in zip(oscillations, patterns):
        ops.append(op)
        if len(ops) > sequence_length:
            sequence_in = sums[:]
            sequence_out = op[0]
            yield (sequence_in, sequence_out)
            ops.pop(0)
            sums.pop(0)
        sums.append(sum(op))
```